# Why is it bad to make $output a Symfony command class property

Tags: php, symfony, console, command

I will write some commands to check that everything is alright on my application.

Because theses commands will be executed by a cronjob I would like to format the Output to be exploitable in a log file.

In order to display error messages from anywhere in the command (without passing $output in every method call) I make it a class property and it is very convenient but it seems bad, I know it is bad but I do not know why. Here is an example:

```
<?php
namespace CheckingBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

/**
 * Class CheckingCommand
 *
 */
class CheckingCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * @var OutputInterface $output
     */
    private $output;

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('check:all');
    }

    protected function initialize(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->output = $output;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->checkSqlConnection();
    }

    protected function checkSqlConnection()
    {
        $myConnexion = null; //Try to connect to database
        if (null === $myConnexion) {
            $this->sendError('Cannot connect to MySQL database');
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param string $errorMessage
     */
    protected function sendError($errorMessage)
    {
        $this->output->write(sprintf('%s <error>%s</error>', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), $errorMessage));
    }
}
```

Can someone explain me why it is bad (if it is) ? It would not be better to pass it everywhere like:

```
 $this->checkSqlConnection($output);
```

and

```
 protected function checkSqlConnection(Output $output)
   {
       $myConnexion = null; //Try to connect to database
       if (null === $myConnexion) {
           $output->write('Cannot connect to MySQL database');
       }
   }
```

Should I use Exceptions inside my command with a try/catch and use my sendError method in the catch ? This could be a good way to handle errors but what if I want to display others informations inside a method ?

Comment: This is pretty subjective, but i would guess it is 'bad' because it's not the responsibility of a `command` class  to format output. You should have a `OutputFormatter` or something else handle that responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things i like to point out , 
1) `checkSqlConnection` should not be in the command class , it should be in a separate class (maybe a service)  and you need to expose this class as a service and use it from the command class, your business logic should not be in the command class

2) as you mentioned it's not good code to pass around `$input` and `$output` instances, it's not good because your service class would be  tightly coupled with the input/output classes

Solution ? use Monolog instead of `outputInterface`,
as of symfony 2.4 the Console Component is integrated with Monolog and it has console handler which listens to the console events and writes log messages to the console output depending on the log level and the console verbosity

[Read more](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-show-logs-in-console)